# Place string based on the format on an Array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

Hi all sorry if the title is not right but i don't know how to put it in a title haha, my first post!

**explanation**: I have a javascript code in a file and i want to put it as text in an Array!
also heads up, i am using React-ts

*Basically the js file:*

```
console.log('test me')
const data = 'my data'
const numbData = 1233
const myObj = {data: 123123}
const myArr = ['ewqeqw', '132312']
function myFunc(param) {
    console.log(param)
}
myFunc('testFunc')
```

*What i tried:*

```
  const [updated, setUpdate] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const areaRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement | null>(null);
  const codeRef = useRef<HTMLParagraphElement | null>(null);

  const reader = new FileReader();

  function handleChange(event: any) {
    setFile(event.target.files[0]);
  }

  reader.addEventListener('loadend', function () {
    document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML = reader.result;
    setUpdate(true);
  });

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }

  if (updated) {
    let data = codeRef.current?.innerText;
    let bodyTextArray = data?.split(/(\n)/);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(bodyTextArray);
  }
```

**What i get** :
[Console Log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUmUm.png)

**What i want**:

```
["console.log('test me')", "const data = 'my data'",
 "const numbData = 1233", "const myObj = {data: 123123}", 
 "const myArr = ['ewqeqw', '132312']", "function myFunc(param) {
    console.log(param) }", "myFunc('testFunc')"
]
```

Basically every peice of code (variable declaration, functions...) on it's own!

Thank you and any solution would be be appreciated!

Comment: "_Basically every peice of code (variable declaration, functions...) on it's own_": Unless you define **precisely** what these requirements are (very exhaustively, no edge cases or exceptions), it's impossible for anyone to answer this question. What I _think_ you are looking for is to parse the script into [AST](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/0fcbb52b986a10a024c27bd0f757ad6b/2e2c1b57c22f2ef2d3e36c76e30f3169ebb92b91) and then stringify every top-level "item".)

Comment: Thank you for your reply this is basically one solution that i can work with! thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be much easier if you put each statement on a single line (including your `myFunc` function). Then you can just split on newlines:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwA4BsZQDIzAU2UQAo9UQoAuFKAJzwHMAaFAaxlQFEBbVKAT0QBeRHRD4AlNWR1GAbQC6iAN4BYAFCJEEBDMSYCyabLANFwxIoDcGjVoD09lBiyIEiWvgYh0AQ1puAQDueAAmcEFEBEH6eIR2iMBwAcQ6YHoG+G7AiGQUAHSy3MQS+WiYUMT2ADq0APzVYPYSEioJDk4wOVAAFlmZuUT4vAIsyOyouVDtuTnE4xw8fIIAZCuIAISZhfTFLdoIsGDiNppasYb55Mg9xJkSp1oAvrZnnlAgtEiZyKcv6ho0nooPgAB5QCwAA0Bujg6Hw+XQcAYxAA5CC9Nx8KiJDD0hDQr4oL4LKjuIJCcTUXi9MduAAjAAiRJJIgAjAAmADMXJpEPJAHl6QArCzKSm+aicrnS-5A-n8ACCtACIjkqPwQQAjvgtUFUSxUWyudzOaiFBpQJBYO5yQAxcAQYiofy+bitZQHdJwhFIlEu2hu1r-e2OtEYqAOyA4jSQ040n2I5HzFw4OLIYgg8EtU5AA)

```ts
function splitLines (input: string, skipEmpty = true): string[] {
  const lines: string[] = [];

  // split on regular or windows new lines
  for (const line of input.trim().split(/\r?\n/)) {
    // if the line is empty, skip it
    if (skipEmpty && !line.trim()) continue;
    lines.push(line);
  }

  return lines;
}

const text = `
console.log('test me')
const data = 'my data'
const numbData = 1233
const myObj = {data: 123123}
const myArr = ['ewqeqw', '132312']
function myFunc(param) { console.log(param) }
myFunc('testFunc')
`;

console.log(splitLines(text));
```

Compiled JS from the TS playground:

```js
"use strict";
function splitLines(input, skipEmpty = true) {
    const lines = [];
    // split on regular or windows new lines
    for (const line of input.trim().split(/\r?\n/)) {
        // if the line is empty, skip it
        if (skipEmpty && !line.trim())
            continue;
        lines.push(line);
    }
    return lines;
}
const text = `
console.log('test me')
const data = 'my data'
const numbData = 1233
const myObj = {data: 123123}
const myArr = ['ewqeqw', '132312']
function myFunc(param) { console.log(param) }
myFunc('testFunc')
`;
console.log(splitLines(text));
```

If you don't put each statement on one line, you'll have to write you own logic for determining where each "part of your code" begins and ends in the string, and split on that logic.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer! Thing is i don't have control over the text to put each thing on 1 line, i get it like that format and i'm trying to find a way to get the result i need and i am stuck!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use regex in `split` function. You can simply do this:

```
let bodyTextArray = data?.split('\n');
```